# Sheldon Axler 9.10: How to understand the proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I have trouble in understanding the proof of 9.10 in Linear Algebra Done Right (Third Edition). The Theorem is the following:

$\newcommand{\C}{{\Bbb C}}$

> 9.10$\quad$ Minimal polynomial of $T_\C$ equals minimal polynomial of $T$
>
> Suppose $V$ is a real vector space and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ . Then the minimal polynomial of $T_\C$ equals the minimal polynomial of $T$.

The proof given is the following:

> **Proof**
>
> Let $p\in\mathcal{P}(R)$ denote the minimal polynomial of $T$. From 9.9 it is easy to see that $p(T_\C)=(p(T))_\C$, and thus $p(T_\C)=0$.
>
> Suppose $q\in\mathcal{P}(\C)$ is a monic polynomial such that $q(T_\C)=0$. Then $(q(T_\C))(u)=0$ for for every $u\in V$. Letting $r$ denote the polynomial whose $j^{th}$ coefficient is the real part of the $j^{th}$ coefficient of $q$. we see that $r$ is a monic polynomial and $r(T)=0$. Thus $\deg q= \deg r \geqslant \deg p$.
>
> The conclusions of the two previous paragraphs imply that $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $T_\C$, as desired.

I don't understand the sentence "**$r$ is a monic polynomial and $r(T)=0$**" in the second paragraph of the proof. Why $r(T)=0$ here?

Comment: could you explain what $T_c$ is and how it is defined

Comment: $T_c$ is complexification of T. The definition is, suppose $V$ is a real vector space and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$. The complexification of $T$, denoted $T_c$. is the operator $T_c\in\mathcal{L}(V_c)$ defined by $T_c(u+iv)=T_u+i T_v$ for $u,v \in V$.

Comment: While $V_c$ is complexification of $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we write the polynomial $q$ as
\begin{align}
q(t) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_jt^j
\end{align}
where each $a_i \in \Bbb{C}$, and since we assumed $q$ to be monic, we have $a_n = 1$. Then, by definition, we have
\begin{align}
r(t) := \sum_{j=0}^n \text{Re}(a_j) \cdot t^j
\end{align}
Note that $T$ is just the restriction of the complexification $T_c:V_c \to V_c$ to the real vector space $V$, so it is easy to show that $q(T_c) = 0$ implies that $q(T) = 0 $ (as an element of $\mathcal{L}(V)$).

Now, we have
\begin{align}
0 &= q(T) \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^n a_jT^j \\
&= \left( \sum_{j=0}^n \text{Re}(a_j) \cdot T^j \right) + i \left( \sum_{j=0}^n \text{Im}(a_j) 
 \cdot T^j\right)
\end{align}
It follows that both bracketed terms are the zero linear transformation in $\mathcal{L}(V)$. Note that the first term is precisely $r(T)$. Hence, $r(T) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, peek-a-boo. But I still have another question related:): It says “Thus $\deg q= \deg r \geqslant \deg p$” at the end of the second paragraph of the proof. But, in case of $Re(a_j)=0$ and $Im(a_j)\neq0$ for a few of $a_j$, we have $\deg q> \deg r$, isn't it?

Comment: @JackZhou No, We have equality, because the leading coefficient, (which I denoted by $a_n$) is $1$ (because we assumed $q$ is monic). So, $\text{Re}(a_n) = 1$ and $\text{im}(a_n) = 0$. Hence, $q$ and $r$ are both monic polynomials, and their degrees are both $n$ (using my notation above).

Comment: Oh, yes, $q$ is monic, thanks for your time.